# Find and replace a line removing that last part of the line with regex with Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

Here is the line i'm searching for in a very large document

```
Conventional    CountyId=2820   StateId=51  Accomack    Off 06/24/2014 12:48:00 Conventional
```

This regex finds the and selects the line;

```
Conventional.*$
```

What I want to replace that line with is;

```
Conventional    CountyId=2820   StateId=51  Accomack    Off 06/24/2014 12:48:00
```

Basically removing the word Conventional from the end of the line.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

Find what: `(Conventional.+)\sConventional$`
Replace with: `$1`

Answer (score 0):

```
(Conventional.*)\bConventional$
```

Replace by `$1`.